# How to send SMTP email in .NET where FROM address is entered by user

Tags: vb.net, email, outlook

I have a contact form on my website that allows a user to enter their email address and send along with some their inquiry.

I am using smtp to send the email using the following code...

```
Dim objMail As New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
objMail.From = New System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("me@mydomain.com") 
objMail.To.Add(New System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("me@mydomain.com"))
objMail.Subject = "Inquiry from contact page."
objMail.Body = "Message from" + txtFromAddress.Text + message
Dim SmtpMail As New System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient
SmtpMail.Host = "mail.mydomain.com"
SmtpMail.Port = 25
SmtpMail.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("me@mydomain.com", "mypassword")
SmtpMail.Send(objMail)
```

This works fine. However, once the email arrives in my inbox in Outlook, I want to click reply to send an email back to the to the person who made the inquiry. I understand that in order to send an email, I need the Network Credentials so I can't just send an email from any email address right? (because of open relay and spam etc.)

So, how do I do this so when I receive the email, I can click Reply and Outlook will open up a new mail message with the inquirers email address in the To field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `Reply-To` header, which would allow redirecting any recipient replies to a preset mail address.

Your code should look like below:

```
    Dim objMail As New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
    objMail.From = New System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("me@mydomain.com")
    objMail.To.Add(New System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("me@mydomain.com"))
    objMail.Subject = "Inquiry from contact page."
    objMail.Body = "Message from" + txtFromAddress.Text + message

    'ReplyToList usage
    objMail.ReplyToList.Add("john.doe@example.com")

    Dim SmtpMail As New System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient
    SmtpMail.Host = "mail.mydomain.com"
    SmtpMail.Port = 25
    SmtpMail.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("me@mydomain.com", "mypassword")
    SmtpMail.Send(objMail)
```

[MSDN Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

**EDIT:** My previous answer suggested the use of the `ReplyTo` property, which is now [obsolete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.replyto%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Use `ReplyToList` instead.

Comment: Frame your suggestion in the context of the OP's code, and it will be much more useful to everyone.